# "using" keyword for assignment of new C++/CLI class

Tags: c#, memory, c++-cli, idisposable

I have an assembly in 'C++/CLI' which implements certain classes. Let us assume the class is of 'SomeType'.

Now, in an application developed in 'C#', to do the following -

```
while(!Console.KeyAvailable)
{
   using(SomeType type = new SomeType())
   {
       type.doSomething(); //do something
   }
}
```

Would it have any consequence, like memory leaks etc. in any situation, say if there was an unhandled exception or any such?

I read that the `using` keyword should generally be used for a class which implements IDisposable, but for a C++/CLI class?

Answer (score 8):

C++/CLI does not have an equivalent of the *using* keyword.  It took a different approach, one that native C++ programmers expect.  Who are familiar with a very common C++ idiom to implement deterministic destruction, the [RAII pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).  Invoking it requires using "stack semantics".  Works well, the syntax requirements are however pretty obscure.

I'll first show the clumsy way, helpful to demonstrate the syntax differences.  Lets use StreamReader, a disposable class in .NET:

```
String^ ReadTopLineFromFile(String^ path) {
    StreamReader^ reader = gcnew StreamReader(path);
    try {
        return reader->ReadLine();
    }
    finally {
        delete reader;
    }
}
```

The try/finally is what makes code exception-safe, if the ReadLine() throws an exception then the StreamReader object is still disposed and the lock on the file is guaranteed to be released.  This is code that the C# compiler emits automatically when you use the `using` statement.  Also note the use of the `delete` operator, it in effect calls the StreamReader::Dispose() method.  The compiler won't let you write `reader->Dispose()`, using the operator is mandatory.

Now the *using* version that the C++/CLI compiler supports.  You invoke stack semantics by emulating the way the native C++ compiler treats a C++ object that's allocated on the stack.  Like this:

```
String^ ReadTopLineFromFile(String^ path) {
    StreamReader reader(path);
    return reader.ReadLine();
}   // <== disposed here
```

Note the missing ^ hat on the variable name, normally required when it stores a reference type reference.  Intentionally omitting it is what invokes the pattern.  No explicit `gcnew` call required, the compiler emits it automatically.  Also note that you no longer use `->` to dereference the object, you now use `.`

The C++/CLI compiler automatically generates the try/finally blocks as well as the delete operator call.  Which is emitted at the closing brace of the scope block.  Just like the native C++ compiler does it.  While it *looks* like the managed object is allocated on the stack, that's just an syntactical illusion, it is still on the GC heap.

Syntax is very different of course, the only real hangup with the feature.  Knowing when to use the ^ hat and when to rely on stack semantics is something that needs to be learned, takes a while.

Comment: Can one use that feature to initialize variables from factory methods?

Comment: There are still some elements which are confusing. If, for example, I instantiate an object of a CLI `ref` class in C#. When the object goes out of scope, is the memory released automatically, or does a `dispose` need to be called on it explicitly to release memory. Assume I am not using a `using` wrap.

Comment: Only the garbage collector ever releases the memory for a managed object.  It does so when it has to, never when it "goes out of scope".  IDisposable has nothing to do with memory management, it just ensures that an unmanaged resource is released deterministically instead of waiting for the GC to get around it.  Which can take a while.  In this particular case it ensures the file is closed as soon as feasible.  Keeping files open for an unpredictable amount of time is not a good idea.